# Linking ::after element on multiple slideshow items...only first one works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow and for each slideshow I have an ::after element like this:

```
.views-field.views-field-title .field-content:after {
    content: url('../images/myimage.svg');
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -21px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

I want to create a link for the element but only the first link works, it doesn't work on subsequent slideshow items.

```
  $('.views-field.views-field-title .field-content').after().click(function () {
   window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
  });
```

Do i need to iterate over this using foreach?

Answer (score 0):

The [`after` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is used for inserting content *after* the selected element(s).

```js
$('h1').after('<p>Small text</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Big Text</h1>
```

You [can't directly select pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) since they aren't actual DOM elements. So you won't be able to make the `:after` content clickable, what you have "working" at the moment is you're inserting some dummy element and making it clickable.

In this case, you should replace the `:after` content with a proper DOM element (such as a `<a>` tag) and style that element accordingly.